# Why has Erlang far more real world usage than Haskell in terms of IO centric services?

Tags: haskell, io, erlang, distribution

Today we all know that Erlang as a language is very heavily used out in the industry.

It provides a very good soft-realtime scheduling with reductions which allows you get very low latency and very known latency without hogging a core.

Both Erlang and Haskell are based on the epoll for linux systems. Usually the IO of the OS is the constraint when programming languages / vm tries to be efficient.

Haskell has better support for parallelism but again things that exist in Erlang has been ported to Haskell as well. Think supervisor, distribution (Cloud Haskell) ect.

Why are Erlang still being used so heavily, Facebook, Whatsapp, Wooga, Amazon, Gaming industry.

Two things are superior as I know it in Erlang preemptive scheulding and hot code swapping (not a concern for IO though).

Is it the pragmatic approach to side-effects? Is the IO Monad in Haskell introducing a lot of overhead? Or is it just that the preemptive scheduling in Haskell just can't come close to Erlang and this is what's becoming a problem when you have over 2 million tcp connections to one server?

Comment: I'd say their current usage pattern has been shaped by their respective historical roots: Haskell was started as a research project (academical roots) while Erlang was built to be used in critical telecommunication servers (industrial roots).

Comment: Your question is extremely interesting, it, however, isn't a question, but a interesting subject for discussion. :)